# Red Hat Linux and Monitoring User Sessions

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

Is it possible to tap into or monitor a user session from say a root user? Meaning, observing the user's GUI desktop and all? This would be similar to the Windows Assistance Tool.

Comment: With or without their knowledge? Requiring them to intiate a session or not?

Comment: Without. It is for a legitimate application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got the right impression, you could install [**rdesktop**](http://www.rdesktop.org/#download) and have similar functionality to RDC.

Alternatively, VNC is always a nice option. If you are looking for something more specific functionality, mention it and I'll update this answer.

The best tutorial to configure a monitoring setup w/multiple screens at once is here: http://thetechnologyteacher.wordpress.com/vncthumbnailviewer/

Comment: Would this lock out the current user session or see what the user is doing?

Comment: VNC allows shared sessions, i've done and used it it on Xvnc a few times in the past...

Comment: Re: lockout - it depends on OS. If it's a server edition, rdesktop spins a new session. For desktop systems it locks out other users. If you want to play it safe, you should run VNC.

Comment: @mjb: My other question is does this allow a supervisor to monitor?

Comment: Absolutely - The full tutorial you would want is here -- http://thetechnologyteacher.wordpress.com/vncthumbnailviewer/  I'll add that to the solution.